# CakePHP - database config based on URL

Tags: cakephp

What is the best way in CakePHP to have multiple database configuration that is going to be used based on environment?

Say I have a staging, prod and dev server.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set it in your constructor.

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    var $live = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'mysql.live.com',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
    );

   var $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
    );


        public function __construct() {
        if (isset($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
            if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'localhost') === false) {
                $this->default  = $this->live;
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

This will basically switch your configuration based on where you are.

Comment: I found this great article that provides a pretty robust way of setting up this method of managing DB profiles based on environments: 
http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-cakephp-apps-on-appfog-the-right-way/

Answer (score 5):

I got this (my development domain ends with '.dev');

**In Bootstrap.php**

```
define('IS_LIVE',!(strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'dev') !== false));
```

**In database.php**

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG
{
    var $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'login' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxx',
        'database' => 'xxxx',
        'prefix' => '',
    );

    var $production = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'login' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'database' => 'xxxx',
        'prefix' => '',
    );

    function __construct()
    {
        if (IS_LIVE) {
            $this->default = $this->production;
        } else {
            $this->default = $this->default;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IN cake 1.3 it does not work. Cake returns sql errors" SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;"