# Change Cakephp database config at console command

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I've got an application with a unique database for each URL, similar to this answer: [CakePHP - database config based on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382826/cakephp-database-config-based-on-url)

That works fine, but I also need to run some console commands on each of the databases. I'd like to use parameters, so I would use something like this:

```
cake consoleCommand databaseConfig
```

Ideally, this would set the database to 'databaseConfig' for the entire application, then run the 'consoleCommand'. The problem I'm running into is that the DATABASE_CONFIG class is loaded and run before the consoleCommand is run. I've tried at that point to use things like $this->Model->setDataSpource in the console, but Model doesn't seem to be available in the console at that point either.

I've toyed with setting a config setting and just looking that up before accessing the models, but it won't work on __construct(), so I've had to tie it into all the before* methods. This seems a little bit of a kludge to me:

```
class AppModel extends Model
```

{

```
private function _before() {

    $conn = Configure::read('dbConnection');
    if(!empty($conn))
        $this->setDataSource($conn);
}

public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    $this->_before();
    parent::beforeValidate();
}

public function beforeDelete($bool = true) {
    $this->_before();
    parent::beforeDelete($bool);
}

public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    $this->_before();
    parent::beforeFind($queryData);
}

public function beforeSave($options=array()) {
    $this->before();
    parent::beforeSave($options);
}
```

}

I'd appreciate any insight into this.