# Data Source missing

Tags: cakephp

I run my CakePHP project on localhost. When I fill form, after clicking submit button it shows the following error:

> Missing Datasource Configuration
>
> Error: The datasource configuration Array was not found in
>   database.php.

I actually configured a datasource it and it looks like:

class DATABASE_CONFIG {

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'arwinder',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'sh_db',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'arwinder',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'sh_db',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

}
... but it's getting ignored.

Comment: actually i configured it and it looks like:
public $default = array(
  'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
  'persistent' => false,
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'login' => 'arwinder',
  'password' => 'root',
  'database' => 'sh_db',
  'prefix' => '',
  //'encoding' => 'utf8',
 );
but it's getting ignored.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question.

Comment: please tell me the solution.

Comment: Right now, I'm too busy editing questions for lazy posters.

Comment: post your model. you are probably overriding the default datasource in there or another model.

Comment: please when you get free, then solve my problem

Comment: I've just done it. But if you insist on being so insolent I'll remove my answer.

Comment: LetterSticker I'm editing my question...please tell me the solution.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I am using the built-in Apache/PHP in Mac OS X Mavericks, I am also using Codeigniter in this same server, Codeigniter is able to connect to postgres whitout problem, I also made a postgres test scripts that is also beign able to connect to postgres, I double checked my cakePHP database.php config file, what culd I check for ? thanks --- public $default = array(
'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
'persistent' => false,
'host' => 'localhost',
'login' => 'cake',
'password' => 'cake',
'database' => 'cake',
'schema' => 'cake');

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to work with data sanitation (it's a weird use case, what can I say).

The documentation for [sanitize::escape](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#Sanitize::escape) says,

> "The name of the *database* to quote the string for, as named in your
>   app/Config/database.php file."

It does not, in fact, take the name of the database eg. 'mydatabase' nor does it accept the host eg. 'localhost', **nor does it accept the 'datasource' eg. 'Database/Mysql'**. When given any of these VALUES, you get the error mentioned in the question.

What you actually need is the name of the "Datasource" to use. Again, the documentation for 'Datasource' fails to answer this topic.

I was stumped. So I searched for that error and found this unanswered post.

I finally found a solution thorough shear dumb luck, and as this post is still the highest result for this error on Google, I came back to answer it.

What you actually need is the variable name (key not value) as listed in the above mentioned config file. eg. $default or $test or $what_have_you. You then provide 'default', 'test' or 'what_have_you' depending on hostname.

Here's what boggles my mind the most. If the Datasource changes from 'production' to 'testing' and also 'local_dev' knowing which one is in use at any given time is critical to making Sanitise:escape() work.

But hold on a second... if you're doing that, you basically set the datasource to $default using a constructor method [as documented here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382826/cakephp-database-config-based-on-url) so in all actuality, this mysterious 'Datasource' it's almost always going to be 'default' unless it's set on the fly, as an override, in your model which would be known while you're Sanitizing for a manual query anyway.

In fact, the default for this parameter is indeed, 'default'. It's not a required parameter at all, but because the documentation doesn't list it as optional or provide a defined default parameter (on that particular page) one might assume that it is required.

Anyway, the answer is to not provide a $datasource unless you are using [$useDBConfig](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usedbconfig) to specify a different datasource in your Model already.